# Chrome v50 network inspector really slow

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

today my chrome is gone to v50 and I noticed a dramatic slowing when trying to open request/response headers detail in the devtools.
Am I the only one?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Extremely slow on network request / response header details after upgrade to v50.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem on Version 50.0.2661.102 m. Only the headers tab on the network inspector has this problem.

Comment: Is there a bug ticket in the Chrome project for this? It's fairly annoying and I'm sure we'd be happy to +1 it if someone found it. I tried looking but couldn't track anything down.

Comment: Same issue here with version 51. As @Frank said, it only happens with the headers tab. I haven't found a bug ticket either so I posted on the devtools google group [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/PjV2C899y-M).
Also, I installed Chromium (v50) on my Linux environment  and the issue is not present.

Comment: It seems to be the 'Request headers' section in the 'Headers' tab. If you collapse that, it will solve the problem. Of course, it won't help if you have to keep it open to inspect the request headers, but in my case I rarely have to look at that section.

Answer (score 2):

I am having the exact same problem after I upgrade to build 50.0.2661.xxx, and I don't use any theme. For now I just have to downgrade it to build 49.0.2623.xxx.

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome v51 fix this issue

Edit. It seems not

Comment: At least for me on Windows, Version 51.0.2704.84 m (64-bit) continues to have this problem.  Switching to the Headers tab locks the window up for 5+ seconds.  If the call contains a JSON payload, expanding each level of the object locks up the window for another 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The bug report is available [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=622810) on the chromium tracker.
According to the comment, the issue is fixed for v52.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue over the last week. Finally figured out it was a dark theme extension I was using for my dev tools. (DevTools Theme: Zero Dark Matrix) Removing it fixed the issue.

Answer (score -3):

I also noticed the same behaviour in v50. Updating to V51 fixes the issue.